# How do I make a bot to message every hour on discord without using a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want to make a python bot that sends a message to a specific discord channel every hour, I searched up online but I only got tutorials using discord bots. I want to send the message from my OWN account
and not a discord bot, I am a newbie too so i cant understand too complex codes!
Thanks!

Comment: you can use [`discord webhook`](https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/), but its still not your own account

Comment: Userbot (logging in with personal discord account programmatically) is against Discord TOS. I'd suggest using a webhook (mentioned above) or a bot account instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic bot you could use to post every hour; as Taku mentioned Discord TOS would be violated using a userbot.

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

# Init the discord client
discord_client = discord.Client()

# The channel ID you want the bot to send your message to (Right click channel -> Copy ID) 
channel_id = 000077777777770000

# Set the channel object using our channel ID number
channel = discord_client.get_channel(channel_id)

# List we will use these in the example to send random messages to the server
messages = [ "Hi I'm a bot!", "I'm just talking so you don't think I'm inactive!", "Blah blah blah  blah blah!", "Add however many you like me to say in here!" ]

# Single message to get sent to the server string
single_message = "This will send over and over if multi_message = False."

# We will use this boolean to determine if we are just sending message string or a random one from messages list
multi_message = False
        
# Create a loop task for every 60 minutes [1 hour]
@tasks.loop(minutes = 60)
async def send_message():
    # Call channel so we can modify it's value
    global channel
    # Make sure channel isn't null
    if channel == None:
        channel = discord_client.get_channel(channel_id)
    # Wait for the discord bot to load before we start posting
    await discord_client.wait_until_ready()
    # Check to see if we are going to be sending different messages every hour or not
    if multi_message:
        # Print to output
        print("Posted random message.")
        # Send message to Discord channel
        await channel.send(f"{random.choice(messages)}")
    else:
        print("Posted single message")
        await channel.send(f"{single_message}")

# On bot ready
@discord_client.event
async def on_ready():
    # Check to see if we are going to be sending different messages every hour or not
    if multi_message:
        print("* Sending random messages to the channel...")
    else:
        print("* Sending single message to the channel...")

    # Start the message sending loop
    send_message.start()

    # Finished setting up
    print("Bot ready.")

# Launch the Discord bot
print("+ Loading Discord message posting bot...")
discord_client.run("GET YOUR DISCORD TOKEN FROM DISCORD DEVELOPER PORTAL")
```

In the #comments it's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Even knowing the risks of being banned, if he wants to run this code on his own account, I recommend this tutorial on how to get the account token: [How to Find Your Discord Token](https://youtu.be/YEgFvgg7ZPI).
And then specify in the code:
`discord_client.run("YOUR_TOKEN", bot=False)`.
For a better handling of the API for user accounts, I recommend using a specific library of self-bots, such as [discord.py-self](https://github.com/dolfies/discord.py-self).